# Как преобразовать String, который представляет собой число в шестнадцатеричной системе исчисления, в значение int?

Tags: java

Можете помочь, пожалуйста. Вроде легко, но вообще идей нет.

```
Пример:
аргумент: “CAFE”
результат: 51966
```

Comment: А как бы вы вручную это делали? Вот точно такой же алгоритм и можно было бы хотя бы попытаться реализовать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для этого достаточно воспользоваться встроенным в класс `Integer` методом `parseInt`

```
int number = Integer.parseInt("CAFE", 16);
System.out.println(number); //51966
```

если число попадется совсем большое, то есть класс, принимающий целые числа произвольной размерности

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("Thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog", 36);
System.out.println(big); // 2420279590275804445606588463955072096420804747701564608
```

но это уже не примитивный тип и другая история

Answer (score 3):

```
Long.parseLong("CAFE", 16);
```

Не рекомендую пользоваться Integer'ом, иногда попадаются слишком большие числа.